# how to remove of y -axis label in chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts, highcharts

could you please tell me remove labels y axis labels .I make a simple chart using fusion library .
http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes.html?chart=area2d
I saw some y axis label **0$,4$,12$..etc** I want to remove that label .I need to show chart like this as shown in image [![enter image description here][1]][1]
http://jsfiddle.net/Tu57h/135/

can we show this on right side as shown in image ?

here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/Tu57h/135/

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var salesChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'msarea',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '450',
        height: '300',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Sales of Liquor",
                "subCaption": "Previous week vs current week",
                "xAxisName": "Day",
                "numberPrefix": "$",
                "paletteColors": "#0075c2,#1aaf5d",
                "bgColor": "#ffffff",
                "showBorder": "0",
                "showCanvasBorder": "0",
                "plotBorderAlpha": "10",
                "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
                "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
                "legendShadow": "0",
                "plotFillAlpha": "60",
                "showXAxisLine": "1",
                "axisLineAlpha": "25",                
                "showValues": "0",
                "captionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
                "divlineColor": "#999999",                
                "divLineIsDashed": "1",
                "divLineDashLen": "1",
                "divLineGapLen": "1",
                "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
                "toolTipColor": "#ffffff",
                "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
                "toolTipBgColor": "#000000",
                "toolTipBgAlpha": "80",
                "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
                "toolTipPadding": "5",
            },

            "categories": [
                {
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "label": "jan 2015"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "label": "feb 2015"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "label": "mar 2015"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "label": "may 2015"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "label": "jun 2015"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "label": "jul 2015"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "label": "aug 2015"
                        },{
                            "label": "sep 2015"
                        },{
                            "label": "oct 2015"
                        }
                        ,{
                            "label": "nov 2015"
                        },{
                            "label": "dec 2015"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],

            "dataset": [
                {
                    "seriesname": "Previous Week",
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "value": "13000"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "value": "14500"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "value": "13500"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "value": "15000"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "value": "15500"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "value": "17650"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "value": "19500"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    })
    .render();
});
```

Comment: have you tried setting `showYAxisValues='0'`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's shown on the right side of your image are trendlines. You can remove the y-axis labels with `showYAxisValues: "0"` in your chart setup, and add trendlines with:

```
"trendlines": [
  {
    "line": [
      {
          "startvalue": "12000",
          "color": "#1aaf5d",
          "valueOnRight": "1",
          "displayvalue": "$12K"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Tu57h/138/

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if the API offers such functionality. However, to hide the y-axis labels, you may target the section of the DOM created by the API and hide it.

```
setTimeout(function () {
        $('#chart-container .fusioncharts-yaxis-0-gridlabels').eq(0).hide();
    }, 50);
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Tu57h/137/ ( I couldn't get it working on jsfiddle but it works fine when running on local machine).