# how to use customise hight chart as shown in image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

could you please tell me remove labels y axis labels .I make a simple chart using highchart library .
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/areaspline
I saw some y axis label **0,2.5,5..etc** I want to remove that label .I need to show chart like this as shown in image [![enter image description here][1]][1]
http://jsfiddle.net/19bxgykz/1/

can we show this on right side as shown in image ?

here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/19bxgykz/1/

```
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'areaspline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Average fruit consumption during one week'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 250,
            y: 300,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Monday',
                'Tuesday',
                'Wednesday',
                'Thursday',
                'Friday',
                'Saturday',
                'Sunday'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit units'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: ' units'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            areaspline: {
                fillOpacity: 0.8
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402753/how-to-remove-of-y-axis-label-in-chart. That one is using fusion charts, but question header is identical. Possibly a homework assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify yAxis with the following code

```
yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
            enabled:false
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the labels on yAxis from the left then you can use `opposite` property. LIke this in the config:

```
yAxis : {
  opposite:true,
  //other options
}
```

See the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/19bxgykz/1/

Comment: I think you pasted in the wrong link. This one is identical to the original.